# ¿Como compruebo si el usuario tiene un programa instalado en un script?

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy haciendo un script de bash y me gustaría saber como puedo comprobar si el usuario tiene instalado algún programa. Algunos ejemplos que yo conozco son [**airgeddon**](https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon) y [**the lazy script**](https://github.com/arismelachroinos/lscript).
Este último, por ejemplo, cambia el color de las opciones del menú a rojo si has seleccionado alguna opción no instalada.
Por lo menos saber la parte del script en el que lo comprueba para mirarlo yo.
Gracias.

Comment: Saludos, es mucho mejor si agregas lo que has avanzado hasta el momento para darte una mejor respuesta..!!

Comment: De momento (lo que llevo esta madrugada) le voy definiendo algunas cosas, pero la idea sería poner en el menú principal una opción para instalar paquetes y demás que el programa pueda necesitar. Para esto lo ideal sería que antes mirara los programas que ya están instalados de esta supuesta lista de programas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es fácil comprobar si un usuario tiene un ejecutable en su `$PATH` usando el comando `which`. Si se trata del usuario actual, falta solo:

```
which $ejecutable >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    echo "'$ejecutable': Encontrado!" || 
    echo "'$ejecutable': No encontrado!"
```

Puedes guardar este comando como una función:

```
existe(){ 
    which "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
        echo "'$1': Encontrado!" || 
        echo "'$1': No encontrado!"

}
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ existe 'ls'
'ls': Encontrado!
$ existe 'mimo'
'mimo': No encontrado!
```

Pero fíjate que esto no te ayuda saber si esta instalado un paquete que instala una librería, por ejemplo, o otras cosas que no sean ejecutables. Además, una vez sepas si esta o no el ejecutable, instalarlo es muy complicado ya que dependerá totalmente del sistema operativo. Incluso si te interesa solo el Linux, dependerá de la distribución.

Tendras entonces que escribir código que detecta el sistema y cambia el comando de instalación en función de ello. Unos ejemplos de diferentes comandos para instalar el mismo paquete:

- Ubuntu/Debian/Kali/Mint etc

  ```
  sudo apt install rename
  ```
- RedHat/Fedora/CentOS etc.

  ```
  sudo dnf install prename
  ```
- Arch/Manjaro etc.

  ```
  sudo pacman -S perl-rename
  ```

Estos tres instalan el mismo programa, el `perl-rename` pero el comando y el nombre del paquete cambian. Y solo mostré tres familias de Linux.

Todo esto es para decir que lo mejor es simplemente mirar si el ejecutivo esta en el `$PATH` y, sino, decir a tu usuario que lo instale. Al menos que sepas que tu script será usado solamente en una distribución especifica.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo de la distribución no es un problema porque en un principio va a ser solo para debian.

Answer (score 2):

¿Pero, qué tal si el ejecutable no está en una carpeta de su variable `PATH`?

En cualquier caso, en el caso de lo basado en Debian, puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
$ sudo apt list --installed 2>/dev/null| grep -m1 "^<programa>"
```

Por ejemplo

```
$ sudo apt list --installed 2>/dev/null| grep -m1 "^python3"
python3/xenial,now 3.5.1-3 amd64 [installed]
```

El `grep -m1` va a acortar la salida al primer resultado. Puedes eliminar el parámetro `-m1` para ver todo lo que está instalado con ese nombre.

También puedes usar.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -P "ii\s+<programa>" -m1
```

Y es semejante al anterior, sólo que usas una expresión regular de *perl* que busca la cadena que contenga "ii" al inicio, seguido de múltiples espacios en blanco y después un nombre de programa, por ejemplo.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -P "ii\s+python" -m1
ii  python                                 2.7.12-1~16.04                             
amd64
```

Comment: Gracias, también me sirve.
Hace poco además se me ocurrió otra manera con el comando which <comando>.
Si el output es "", no está instalado.

Comment: @ravi0li No necesariamente, si la salida es vacía, sólo signfica que no está en una carpeta listada en tu variable `PATH`. Puede que esté instalado pero no localizable en tu `PATH`, en ese caso abría que únicamente modificar el `PATH` y no descargar, desempaquetar o todo eso de nuevo.

Comment: pues tambien es verdad xd